# Increase text value problem only when double click

Tags: java, android

when i try to increase text value with button i actually have to press it 2 times to increase once, what is really annoying.
I use checkbox

There is my code:

```java
        TextView tvCounter;
    Button btnIncrement;
    private CheckBox i1, i2, i3;
TextView tvCounter2;

    int counter=0;
    int counter2=0;

    private void initialStates(Intent intent) {
        i1=findViewById(R.id.q1_1);
        i2=findViewById(R.id.q1_2);
        i3=findViewById(R.id.q1_3);
    }

    btnIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                tvCounter2.setText(String.valueOf(counter2));

                if (i1.isChecked())
                    counter++;

                if(i2.isChecked())
                    counter2++;

                if (i3.isChecked())
                    counter2++;
            }
        }); }
}
```

Comment: Maybe increase the counter before you print its value?

Comment: thanks, it worked:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increment them first, then set the values.

```
btnIncrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {         
        if (i1.isChecked())
            counter++;

        if(i2.isChecked())
            counter2++;

        if (i3.isChecked())
            counter2++;
        tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        tvCounter2.setText(String.valueOf(counter2));
    }
}); }
}
```

Comment: No problem, but It would be great if you select the answer as correct :)

Comment: Hmm still not accepted huh. Well, here is an upvote

Comment: Srry i m new to stackoverflow, i didn t know how to do that.. now i checked it.